# how to implement a http poller using rxjs timer

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

In one of my angular project, i implemented a http poller using rxjs timer.
whenever http response is delayed more than the polling interval , the pending request is getting cancelled.

The logic used is demonstrated at https://rxviz.com/v/VOKjA9Mo. Here expected result is 1 to 5. But it seems that sometimes the mockApiCall observable is cancelled randomly (when the response time is 800 millis).

```
let n = 0

function mockApiCall(){
  // delays 400 or 800 millis randomly
  n++
  return Rx.Observable.of([n])
                .delay(400 + Math.round(Math.random()) * 400)
}

Rx.Observable
  .timer(500, 500)
  .switchMap( _=>mockApiCall()).take(5)
```

How to avoid cancelling of inner observable used in this timer. ie timer should wait until the api call is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [`exhaustMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap) instead of `switchMap` (I'm a little confused from your description):

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable only if the previous projected Observable has completed.